# Datepicker Prev next icon is not displaying

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery UI Datepicker which is not showing prev next icons. I tried but i couldn't find solution.

```
/* states and images */
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; }
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; }
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsHeader}*/; }
.ui-state-default .ui-icon { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png)/*{iconsDefault}*/; }
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsHover}*/; }
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsActive}*/; }
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png)/*{iconsHighlight}*/; }
.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png)/*{iconsError}*/; }
```

Comment: And you've checked the console to see that the url to the image is correct.

Comment: Are all images copied and in the correct location?

Comment: @Mivaweb images is in correct location

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which shows your problem? Under the `Frameworks & Extensions` area you can select jQuery and click the jQuery UI checkbox to load in jQuery UI.

Comment: Add tag and remove please help.